# Android sdk web page object size too small

Tags: android, mp3, uri, playback

I have an Android Morse code tutor app that has been online for a couple years, and revisions have been made during that time. I decided to make a revision that allows the user to play an mp3 file from a web site. The problem is as follows:

The file plays perfectly in the android simulator, but on the actual device, the user is required to touch the play button, which is way too small. See code below:

uri = Uri.parse("http://www.arrl.org/files/media/W1AW/morse/Archive/10%20WPM%20files/051110WPM.mp3");
startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by looking at a few dozen web sites. I used media player and it works great!